# Webpack import angular in angular-webpack-workflow demo project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I'm inspecting this Webpack demo project https://github.com/Foxandxss/GermanWords-ng1-webpack. This project contains in several files this line (features/home/index, features/login/index):

```
import angular from 'angular';
```

I don't understand - if 'angular' library will be included several times in result js file because this library exists in several source files? I've looked at webpack config file, but can't understand. Please, can you clear this questions?

Comment: Webpack will build a finished file from all your sourcefiles, only pulling in the required components that exists as imports. All dependencies in your files needs to be imported where it is used. This is very neat, since all dependencies is imported where its used, making it easier to split your code into many files without making a mess on what belongs where.

Comment: So to add up, angular will only exist once in the final file built by webpack, regardless of how many files that imports it

Answer (score 0):

It's just to be sure that angular will be available for every module. Imagine you use a feature to be a new standalone site, you will have already the code ready. Always think like every feature is a standalone (handle routes, dependencies, controllers, views etc.).

Webpack will handle the dependencies and inject only once angular, dont worry. Like @thsorens says in comments : "All dependencies in your files needs to be imported where it is used."

Oh and for furthermore, i've found this yeoman generator base on Foxandxss work : https://github.com/Aleksion/generator-angular-webpack-babel

Have fun.